# git push all branches with just a single trunk?

Tags: git, logging, push, fetch, pull

So, somehow a fellow coworker was not seeing any of my updates/pushes. For some reason or another, I was pushing, but he was not seeing the latest in the log.
So, naturally, they blamed me for not pushing. So, they came over and verified I was pushing. So, we tried to do a fetch, then a push. That didn't seem to work. So, finally we clicked the 'push all branches' checkbox and the log finally got the update. I don't know if it was a bug or do I really have to 'push all branches' when there is only one trunk? There are no branches. Maybe FETCH_HEAD is a branch? It certainly appears that way. I found the settings where I can disable seeing the 'FETCH_HEAD' branch. So, the conclusion is. Push all branches, even though it does not appear to have any branches? I guess there really is no harm in pushing all branches.

Comment: Yep, you do need to actually look carefully at what your branch is called, what its upstream is called, what your co-worker's branch is called and what upstream _that_ is tracking, what branch you have checked out when you push, what branch they have checked out when they pull, etc. etc.

Comment: You mention a push all *checkbox*, so that means you're using some gui on top of git.  Please specify what tool you are using, as you may be encountering a behavior peculiar to that tool.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using Tortoise Git.

Answer (score 0):

There is not "trunk" in git. `master` is a branch (technically like all other branches, but usually with the special meaning of being the "main branch"). Pushing all branches (`git push --all`) does exactly what it is supposed to, instead of just pushing the current branch.

Either you or your colleagues are working on a different branch or your branches have different names locally and/or the server.

You could give a shot at the following commands to find out about the problem:

- `git branch -avv`: To see all branches and their corresponding tracking branches.
- `git remote -v`: To see all remotes.

You need to make sure that you and your colleagues are connected through the same branch (which may be named differently) and remote (same here).

Comment: Thanks. I am becoming more adept to using Git. Specifically Tortoise Git. But I have been reading and do intend to figure out what specifically was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be considering throwing your hands up and saying "well, I don't understand it, but this seems to work so I'll just do that from now on".  I don't recommend it, because it might work as you want for now but might have unwanted side-effects in the future.  There certainly *are* times when pushing all branches without meaning to could be a problem, or might even cause a push to be rejected.

Without knowing what tool(s) you're using on top of git, I can't say why you're getting this particular behavior.  (I've asked for clarification in comments, and if it turns out to be a tool I know about I'll update with more info.)

For git itself, the main reason that `git push` would not, by default, do what you want would be if you do not at the moment have the branch checked out[1].  Since you say there aren't multiple branches, that suggests that you might be in "detached head" state - i.e. maybe you checked out a specific commit, or maybe you checked out a tag.

If that turns out to be the explanation, then knowing that will matter, because otherwise the next time you commit, the commit won't be added to the branch, and saying `push all branches` might not help in that situation.

---

[1] I should qualify that.  The `push` behavior in git, when you don't specify *what* to push, is very configurable.  I'm describing a typical configuration, but your setup could be different in that regard.

Comment: I do get frustrated. I will grant you that. What works works. I come seeking knowledge. Its the coworkers that name every variable volatile to prevent any problems. What can I say, other than it works. The problem is, that it falls on me when something doesn't work as it should. There are no tags. Just a single branch that I have been committing and pushing to. That's it.  All I can say is what happened and what we did to resolve it. It possibly could be in a detached head state as you mention and maybe pushing all branches solved the error. Thanks